# Set other variables don't work in onViewableItemsChanged FlatList(React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have following function:

```
export default function Home() {
   const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

   const onViewableItemsChanged = React.useRef((info: { viewableItems: ViewToken[], changed: ViewToken[] }) => {
      //Setting new value based on items.
      setValue(4);
      //This code doesn't work.
   });
   
   return(
     <FlatList onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged.current}/>
   )
}
```

setValue doesn't work at all.

Can someone tell me what step am I missing. For reference, I am using Expo latest version for development with typescript support.

Thanks in advance.